# yum install multiple packages including a groupisntall

Tags: yum

I want to have a one liner that installs all the packages I need, but I am unsure of how to include a groupinstall command in this (groupinstall 'Development Tools').

Right now I run this:

```
sudo yum install perl-CPAN wget zlib-devel tcp_wrappers
```

And then this:

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

How can I make this a one liner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get `yum` to do both at the same time, but if it must be one line:

`sudo sh -c "yum install -y perl-CPAN wget zlib-devel tcp_wrappers ; yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'"`

I added the `-y` to avoid the prompt for confirmation from `yum`.

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo yum install perl-CPAN wget zlib-devel tcp_wrappers @'Development Tools'
```

Comment: Ok, you win, I didn't know that syntax to yum. :)

Comment: You, sir, are an engineer.